# Data insert error 10427 conversion of parameters

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, hana

I'm trying to load some data in Hana 2.0 database from Python 3.x Juypter Notebooks and getting an error.
Please advise.

the type of the column is INT as Pregnancies, the structure is as below

[image]

and in the CSV file, the data is a number

[image]

So above data should go to Pregnancies column.

> Error I'm getting, while inserting data is below:-
>
> hdbcli.dbapi.Error: (-10427, "Conversion of parameter/column (1) from
> data type UCS2 (LE) to INT failed (invalid number: not a valid number
> string 'Pregnancies')")

its big script..I'm getting issue in insert method

```
 @staticmethod
    def insert_data(connection,tablename,cols,inlist,data, batch_size):
            sql = 'insert into ' + tablename + inlist
            if len(data) > 0:
                with connection.connection.cursor() as cur:
                    rows_inserted = cur.executemany(sql, data)
    @staticmethod
    def file_load(connection,table_descriptions,cols, inlist, filename,file_count,train_percentage,valid_percentage,test_percentage,batch_size):
        with open(filename, 'r') as my_file:
            reader = csv.reader(my_file, delimiter=',')
            data = list()
            data_list = list()
            load_count = 0
            for row in reader:
                remain_count = file_count - load_count
                if remain_count < batch_size:
                    batch_size = remain_count
                if len(data) <= batch_size:
                    data.append(list(row))
                    if len(data) == batch_size:
                        DataSets.split_data_into_tables(connection,data,table_descriptions,train_percentage,valid_percentage,test_percentage, cols, inlist, batch_size, file_count)
                        load_count += len(data)
                        data = list()
                        print("Data Loaded:{}%".format(math.floor(load_count/file_count*100)))
```

whole code for this is  in below link

https://github.com/SAP-samples/hana-ml-samples/blob/master/Python-API/pal/notebooks/data_load_utils.py

Comment: Are you using a Python script? If you provide this in the question it will be easier to help out. It is likely you have a non-int value in that column, in any event it seems you need to convert the column type while the data is staged in Python before uploading it to Hana.

Comment: I've updated the code ..even I tried changing csv column format as text but still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message text, I’m rather sure that the problem is that the import code tries to read the first line of the CSV file (the line that contains the column names/headers) and  importing these names to the target table is what fails.

To avoid this, just skip the first line of the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

the error says that the data in the column is of type 'UCSE' which is a character encoding standard in which characters are represented by a fixed-length 16 bits (2 bytes) and you have defined the columns as 'INT' type.
so change the type to 'INT' in the CSV file first and then load the data.

Comment: you mean changing to number??not sure how you change to INT datatype in CSV?

Comment: CSV data does not contain type information - thus, there is no way to “change the data type in CSV”.

Comment: @LarsBr. the type of column can be seen and changed using pandas if this is the case.

Comment: @Rubane I think the error is due to the first row of the CSV ie the name of the columns as it is a part of the CSV file just remove the first row and try.as the error has this written-" invalid number: not a valid number string 'Pregnancies'". I didn't notice this.

Comment: @SiddhantRanjan not sure why you mention the pandas library now - it's not mentioned anywhere in the question and the error message has nothing to do with it either. 
But thanks for agreeing with the answer I provided in your last comment.